# Using vector iterators with in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I am attempting to create a vector iterator within a template class I am creating. The following is the trouble code.

```
void editor<T>::insert()
{   
        typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator itr;
        itr it;
        it = this->buffer.begin();

        for(int i = 0; i < line_num -1; ++i)
        {   
            ++it;
        }

        this->buffer.insert(it, user_text);
        std::cout << "Cool, Your new line has been inserted." << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I am getting the following compile error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘it = ((editor<std::basic_string<char> >*)this)->editor<std::basic_string<char> >::buffer.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > > > >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >*]()’
```

I have a feeling the compiler is getting confused with my `typedef` statement above but that is how I have seen to declare the correct iterator, but for some reason it is not working correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the definition of `buffer`?

Comment: @Naveen buffer declaration `std::vector< std::vector<T> > buffer;` It is a multidim vector for my class.

Comment: Can you post the code which calls this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `buffer` is a `std::vector< std::vector<T> >` then `buffer.begin()` is a `std::vector< std::vector<T> >::iterator` or `const_iterator`, so your `typedef` doesn't match.

Comment: what if `T` here is a `std::vector<Type>` ?

Comment: @Naveen: If you look at his error message `T` is `std::basic_string<char>`

Comment: @Naveen I am assuming `T` in the buffer definition and in the code snippet are one and the same. Otherwise `buffer` would be a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>`.

Comment: You got it... As I suspected my `typedef` was buggered up.